# Using Raspberry Pi 3 as a Keylogger

Tags: keyboard

I have a raspberry pi 3 model B, a barcode scanner, and my laptop.
what I want to do is simply using the pi as a keylogger or listener between the laptop and the barcode scanner, so whenever I scan an item, the barcode goes to the laptop and to the pi at the same time. I want the pi simply to log or monitor anything scanned by the barcode scanner. I searched google for this but all the solutions are only for pi zero.

any bits of advice are appreciated.

Comment: Most "solutions are only for pi zero" will work on the normal pi.

Comment: The pi zero has usb OTG and the 3b doesn’t. That may be needed for something like this.